# I cannot pipe a transpose() into a lapply in R

Tags: r, datatable, pipe

The title is a bit complicated, but basically I have something that I am able to do in two steps, and not sure why cannot pipe these two steps.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

c1 <- c("Var1 3.4 2.1","Var2 85 45", "Var3 4.5 1.6", "Var4 -8.5 6.1", "Var5 8.4 4.3", 
        "var6 6.5 4.3", "var7 -8.5 6.6", "var8 4.4 -8.4")
c2 <- c("Var1 3.4 2.1","Var2 85 45", "Var3 4.5 1.6", "Var4 -8.5 6.1", "Var5 8.4 4.3", 
        "var6 6.5 4.3", "var7 -8.5 6.6", "var8 4.4 -8.4")
MWE_List <- list(c1,c2)


MWE_List_2 <- MWE_List %>%
  lapply(., 
         function(x) 
           str_extract_all(x, "-?\\b\\d+\\.?\\d?\\b") %>%
           as.data.table(x) %>%
           transpose(x))
```

yields :

```
 Error in transpose(., x) : 
  fill must be a length 1 vector, such as the default NA
```

whereas not piping within the function but into a next lapply does :

```
> MWE_List_2 <- MWE_List %>%
+   lapply(., 
+          function(x) 
+            str_extract_all(x, "-?\\b\\d+\\.?\\d?\\b") %>%
+            as.data.table(x)) %>%
+   lapply(.,function(x) transpose(x))
> MWE_List_2
[[1]]
     V1   V2
1:  3.4  2.1
2:   85   45
3:  4.5  1.6
4: -8.5  6.1
5:  8.4  4.3
6:  6.5  4.3
7: -8.5  6.6
8:  4.4 -8.4

[[2]]
     V1   V2
1:  3.4  2.1
2:   85   45
3:  4.5  1.6
4: -8.5  6.1
5:  8.4  4.3
6:  6.5  4.3
7: -8.5  6.6
8:  4.4 -8.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example was not reproducible, because `transpose` is a function of both `data.table` and `purrr`. Therefore, I corrected by writing `data.table::transpose`.

But your actual problem was related to the fact that you did not need to write `transpose(x)`, since you were using a pipe `transpose()` was enough.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

c1 <- c("Var1 3.4 2.1","Var2 85 45", "Var3 4.5 1.6", "Var4 -8.5 6.1", "Var5 8.4 4.3", 
        "var6 6.5 4.3", "var7 -8.5 6.6", "var8 4.4 -8.4")
c2 <- c("Var1 3.4 2.1","Var2 85 45", "Var3 4.5 1.6", "Var4 -8.5 6.1", "Var5 8.4 4.3", 
        "var6 6.5 4.3", "var7 -8.5 6.6", "var8 4.4 -8.4")
MWE_List <- list(c1,c2)


MWE_List2 <- MWE_List %>%
 lapply(function(x) 
         str_extract_all(x, "-?\\b\\d+\\.?\\d?\\b") %>%
         as.data.table(x) %>%
         data.table::transpose())

MWE_List3 <- MWE_List %>%
 lapply(function(x) 
         str_extract_all(x, "-?\\b\\d+\\.?\\d?\\b") %>%
         as.data.table(x)) %>%
 lapply(function(x) data.table::transpose(x))

identical(MWE_List2, MWE_List3)
#> [1] TRUE
```

PS: when you use a pipe you don't need to specify `.,` at the beginning of each function.

Comment: I tend to think `.,` increases readibility, so I tend to put it when I can. Thank you for the answer, I was a bit lost. Not sure why it works fine with the `as.data.table(x)` then and I guess it is safer not to put it

Comment: `%>%` composes a new function call using the `rhs` expression as a template. The design of `%>%` is that the value of the `lhs` evaluated expression gets supplied as an argument to one or more of the formal arguments of new function call. The `.` symbol allows the user to specify which formal argument this gets matched to. If you do not include `.` the value of `lhs` gets matched to the first unmatched formal arg and other unnamed args in `rhs` get matched using positional match. In your example the unnamed arg `x` is matched to formal arg `fill` - illegal, since it is not a length 1 vector.